# Using hashed password for adduser function in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, useradd, shadow, hashsum

Sorry, I´m novice in Linux and I am looking for information, how to create new user account in Debian with pre-defined encrypted password.

I have a function in bash, that if new user´s id´s are not presented in my /etc/passwd file than I run the bash command:

```
adduser -m -p <encrypted-password> <username>
```

so far so good, but all my data including username and password are stored in JSON output and user´s password is already hashed by SHA-512 (for security reasons). User´s password is encrypted by PHP script and sent to JSON:

```
$hashed_password = crypt('Test007', '$6$rounds=5000$StJ.1Wji$');
echo looks like this: $6$rounds=5000$StJ.1Wji$cm6ZVl.XoIiQXaJAVHkqiteUGAqZoJ1Ee3dpHP2a6x6rG/kHg4k7ucMLrzHCvQA1TpQYP4eKnoFITVGcviqjU0
```

After adduser function when I look in my `/etc/shadow` file, I see that the hashed password is different from original one generated by PHP and of course I cannot login the new user with that password in plain text (even if I know it in plain text).

Is there an easy way, how to create user account with pre-defined encrypted password? How to generated hashed password to be accepted by Linux useradd function? I cannot find any solutions on the internet.

Answer (score 4):

That `$6$rounds=5000` is probably part of the problem, because except for the leading `$6`, the entire value passed to [`adduser`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser) has to be a valid hash.  Also (not apparent in your script fragment), the value should be quoted to avoid parameter expansion, e.g.,

```
adduser -m -p '$6$gehr8sgkkX$lMZ5bmb7c4HY76pnn0uUXA5wH51YE0Byp4rIfcA94gWrVvfeNVQsMwoW2erVuxzFScxRvaHOLFMqVSYCjVlTV/' oneshot
```

I used mkpasswd to get a value as suggested in [How to create an SHA-512 hashed password for shadow?](https://serverfault.com/a/410229/291704)

In a quick check here, the value stored in `/etc/shadow` matches the value I used when running adduser.

Comment: I ´ve tried generate sha-512 hash by php **$pass = crypt("myPassword" , "$6$FixedSalt")** but when I do again **useradd -p "$pass" <username>** - what i see in **/etc/shadow** looks still different hash (there is no $6$ at the beginning and it is short). I thinked maybe my PHP hash not corresponds the valid Unix format? What finally worked for me, was hashing inside my bash **openssl passwd -crypt Test007** -> output me: **"jc44wHaeucnHI"**  than I can login with password **"Test007"** to my new user. Can I find similiar function as openssl in PHP?

Comment: In Ubuntu, this is done via the `useradd` command, with the same arguments. For interactive users, you may also want to create their initial directory, and give them a bash shell: `-m -s /bin/bash`